# Spring Bean Dependence - How to Configure Core beans depends On A Web Tier Bean

Tags: spring

In a web configuration, I have a bean, Thymeleaf's TemplateEngine, which relays on servlet. The templateEngine also is used for an Emailservice. And several service beans depend on the EmailService. My Spring configuration is in the following structure:

```
public class WebAppInitializer extends
    AbstractAnnotationConfigDispatcherServletInitializer {


@Override
protected Class<?>[] getRootConfigClasses() {
    return new Class<?>[] { WebSecurityConfig.class, JPAConfig.class,
            CoreConfig.class };
}

@Override
protected Class<?>[] getServletConfigClasses() {
    return new Class<?>[] { WebConfig.class };
}

//....
 }
```

I have tried various approaches without a luck. How to solve this dependence problem?

Comment: This problem in the start-up is solved by using @Lazy on the bean initialization chain. I haven't tested on the runtime. so, I can't say that is a right approach yet.

Comment: Using @Lazy only solves a dependence problem during start-up, but not the configuration problem. I have to create separated beans in the dependence chain to solve this configuration problem.